# Deploying SAPUI5 app to app stores without Cordova

Tags: android, sapui5, sap-smp

Is it possible to deploy a SAPUI5 app stores?

I don't want to use Cordova build as it's a business app.

What are my options?

Comment: Do you mean Google Play store?

Comment: Yes, and Apple's store

Comment: Yes you can deploy a production build.

Answer (score 0):

You will need APK or IPA file to submit your app on App stores. You can use the SAP Mobile Platform SDK to convert your apps. SAP Mobile Platform SDK internally uses CORDOVA ( which beats your purpose I suppose.)

LINK: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide_hat/frameset.htm?784c3a0e1e454c5d8caaf90cf0902835.html